# Issue with transposing a data set using pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am trying to transpose the following data set

```
    CountryName SeriesName    1990  1991    1992    1993    1994
    Afghanistan LitRate       #N/A  #N/A    #N/A    #N/A    #N/A
    Afghanistan AgrValue      #N/A  #N/A    #N/A    #N/A    #N/A
    Afghanistan CropProd      68.35 70.27   65.81   71.38   74.83
    Afghanistan FertCons      #N/A  #N/A    #N/A    #N/A    #N/A
```

It has several more years across the top and and about 100 different series names for each country.  I would like to transpose the data set so that the years are a column and each seriesname is its own column.

I have tried using the following code:

```
    new_panda = df.pivot_table(['1990','1991','1992','1993','1994','1995', '1996', '1997', '1998', '1999'],
                                'CountryName',
                                'SeriesName')
    new_panda.to_csv('wb2.csv')
```

But the end format is not correct.

Any thoughts?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['a','c',1,2],['a','d',4,5],['b','d',8,6],['b','c',7,9]],columns=['Country','Series',1990,1991])

dfmi = df.set_index(['Country','Series'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(dfmi.stack())
df2[df2[0]==5]
```

(There's surely a way to do this without round-tripping through records:)

```
da = array(df2.to_records())
df4 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(da)
df4.columns=['Country','Series','Year','Trait']
```

Comment: It transposes the data, but it makes each country a seperate coulmn.

Comment: I don't understand "the years are a column and each seriesname is its own column." Seems to me there will might be several entries for, e.g., 1990 LitRate, if both Afghanistan and Zambia reported LitRate that year. With this teeny dataset, what's the desired output?

Comment: The data set includes every country and has about 100 attributes for each country - year combination.  The desired output is:                                 
   CountryName as a column with county names as rows,  Years as a column with year values as rows. and LitRate, AgrValue, CropProd, FertCons as columns with their values corresponding to the correct country and year. @cphlewis

Comment: Next time, put the desired output in the original question -- it's fine to edit it -- partly because you can format it legibly there, mostly because it makes the question clear and complete.